# Finding integral solutions of $(xy-47)^2 = x^2 + y^2$

Tags: number-theory

The number of integral solutions (x,y) of $(xy-47)^2 = x^2 + y^2$ are -

I haven't seen a term like $(xy-47)^2$ turning up , is there any way to factorize it, the best I could reach was to open the term on the LHS, after which I don't know how to proceed

I checked at x=0 , got 2 solutions=>(0,47) and (0,-47), similarly 2 solutions for y=0 => (47,0) and (-47,0)

got 4 solutions so far

Comment: Do you know what Linear Algebra is? If you do, why did you use that tag? If you don't, why did you use that tag?

Comment: @jjagmath sorry for the error, can you let me know if this is the correct tag

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are nonzero and $xy \ne 47$ (or equivalently, since $47$ is prime, $(x,y) \notin \{(1,47),(47,1),(-1,-47),(-47,-1)\}$), then $(|x|,|y|,|xy-47|)$ would form a Pythagorean triple.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang That just leads to needing to prove that doesn't form a Pythagorean triple.

Comment: My first try, **which might not succeed**, would be to consult [this section of the Pythagorean triple wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple).  Note that if $1 < d$ is a divisor of any two of $x,y,$ and $(xy - 47)$, then it must also be a divisor of the third.  Therefore, if $x,y,(xy-47)$ is not primitive, you have that there exists $1 < d$ that divides $x,y$ and divides $(xy - 47)$.  This implies that $d$ divides $47$.  ...see next comment.

Comment: So, I would first consider what happens if $x,y,(xy-47)$ is primitive (i.e. no common factors).  Then, I would explore what happens if $x,y,(xy-47)$ is expressible as $d\times a, d\times b, d\times c,$ where $a,b,c$ is a primitive pythagorean triplet.  As discussed, this would imply that $d$ divides $47$.

Comment: Per previous comment, either $x,y,(xy-47)$ is a primitive pythagorean triplet, or $\displaystyle \left(\frac{x}{47}\right),  \left(\frac{y}{47}\right),  \left(\frac{xy}{47} - 1\right),$ is a primitive pythagorean triplet.